# HTC Droid Incredible 2 Imei Location

Tags: htc-droid-incredible-2, imei

what is the location of imei number for android 2.3.3 ?

my phone blacked out after I factory resetted my phone. And need to restore my imei back on my  htc droid incredible 2

Answer (score 2):

go to `settings -> about-phone-> phone identity-> IMSI` is your IMEI number

An International Mobile Subscriber Identity or IMSI (play /ˈɪmziː/) is a unique identification associated with all GSM and UMTS network mobile phone users.

Each Android device is equipped with an IMEI or IMSI or MEID number (depending on the device's radio technology and Carrier) which uniquely identifies the handset. Below are listed a number of ways for you to retrieve such number.

```
The IMEI / IMSI / MEID number can be displayed on most phones by dialing the code *#06#
The IMEI / IMSI / MEID is also usually printed on the compliance plate under the battery
```

Comment: what I want is to restore it. I know my imei number ( saved when I first powered up device to prevent stolen device usage )

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1264021

Comment: badge of 8. not allowed to do so. on the other hand. I think a thank should be enugh. we are not competing in here. we are helping each other.

thanks again.

Comment: @PadmaKumar: Making someone go to another resource to get the answer to their question pretty much defeats the purpose of this site, not to mention linkrot. Can you please update your answer with the information found at that link. Do, of course, provide proper attribution.